# How to wrap a C++ class with a constructor that takes a std::map or std::vector argument with Boost.Python?

Tags: python, c++11, boost, stdvector, stdmap

**Disclaimer**: yes, I *do know* about `boost::python::map_indexing_suite`.

**Task**: I have a C++ class which I want to wrap with Boost.Python. Its constructor takes a `std::map` argument. Here is the C++ header:

```
// myclass.hh
typedef std::map<int, float> mymap_t;

class MyClass {
  public:
  explicit MyClass(const mymap_t& m);
  // ...
};
// ...
```

Here is the Boost.Python wrapper (essential parts only):

```
// myclasswrapper.cc
#include "mymap.hh"
#include "boost/python.hpp"
#include "boost/python/suite/indexing/map_indexing_suite.hpp"

namespace bpy = boost::python;

// wrapping mymap_t
bpy::class_<mymap_t>("MyMap")
     .def(bpy::map_indexing_suite<mymap_t>())
    ;

// wrapping MyClass
bpy::class_<MyClass>("MyClass", "My example class",
  bpy::init<mymap_t>()   // ??? what to put here?
)
  // .def(...method wrappers...)
;
```

This compiles. However, I cannot create the mapped `MyClass` object from the Python side because I don't know what to pass as argument to the constructor. Dictionaries do not get converted to `std::map`-s automatically:

```
# python test
myclass = MyClass({1:3.14, 5:42.03})
```

the interpreter complains (rightly so):

```
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    MyClass.__init__(MyClass, dict)
did not match C++ signature:
    __init__(_object*, std::__1::map<int, float, ...
```

and `MyMap` on the Python side cannot be initialised with a dictionary either.

Having googled away the best part of a day, I could find only examples for "normal" methods taking `std::map` arguments that are mapped with `.def(...)`. And in `.def(...)` you do not have to specify explicitly the arguments of the mapped method, they are magically discovered. With constructors you must use `boost::python::init<...>()`, or at least that is what I understood from the docs.

**Questions**:

1. Shall I add something to the `MyMap` wrapper to help `map_indexing_suite` convert from a Python dictionary?
2. Shall I use a different template argument in `boost::python::init<...>` in the `MyClass` wrapper?
3. Any other ideas...?

**Note**: I have also seen [this accepted answer at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116345/boostpython-possible-to-automatically-convert-from-dict-stdmap/6118691#6118691), then I scrolled down and read the comment by @YvesgereY:

> "For the record, map_indexing_suite solution doesn't work, since no
>   implicit "dict->std::map" from_python converter will be applied."

And I lost faith :-)

Comment: Make a standalone function that will construct the object from a `boost::python::dict`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18793953/3962537) for inspiration.

Comment: @DanMašek : many thanks, your comment was very useful, it pointed me towards converters. I now answered my own question, see below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a nice solution: added a template that can convert a Python dictionary to `std::map`. The logic is based on [this extremely useful primer](https://misspent.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/how-to-write-boost-python-converters/), with slight modifications mostly obtained from [this source file](http://cci.lbl.gov/cctbx_sources/scitbx/stl/map_wrapper.h) and some additional comments.

Below is the template definition:

```
// dict2map.hh
#include "boost/python.hpp"
namespace bpy = boost::python;

/// This template encapsulates the conversion machinery.
template<typename key_t, typename val_t>
struct Dict2Map {

    /// The type of the map we convert the Python dict into
    typedef std::map<key_t, val_t> map_t;

    /// constructor
    /// registers the converter with the Boost.Python runtime
    Dict2Map() {
        bpy::converter::registry::push_back(
            &convertible,
            &construct,
            bpy::type_id<map_t>()
#ifdef BOOST_PYTHON_SUPPORTS_PY_SIGNATURES
            , &bpy::converter::wrap_pytype<&PyDict_Type>::get_pytype
#endif
        );
    }

    /// Check if conversion is possible
    static void* convertible(PyObject* objptr) {
        return PyDict_Check(objptr)? objptr: nullptr;
    }

    /// Perform the conversion
    static void construct(
        PyObject* objptr,
        bpy::converter::rvalue_from_python_stage1_data* data
    ) {
        // convert the PyObject pointed to by `objptr` to a bpy::dict
        bpy::handle<> objhandle{ bpy::borrowed(objptr) };   // "smart ptr"
        bpy::dict d{ objhandle };

        // get a pointer to memory into which we construct the map
        // this is provided by the Python runtime
        void* storage = 
            reinterpret_cast<
                bpy::converter::rvalue_from_python_storage<map_t>*
            >(data)->storage.bytes;

        // placement-new allocate the result
        new(storage) map_t{};

        // iterate over the dictionary `d`, fill up the map `m`
        map_t& m{ *(static_cast<map_t *>(storage)) };
        bpy::list keys{ d.keys() };
        int keycount{ static_cast<int>(bpy::len(keys)) };
        for (int i = 0; i < keycount; ++i) {
            // get the key
            bpy::object keyobj{ keys[i] };
            bpy::extract<key_t> keyproxy{ keyobj };
            if (! keyproxy.check()) {
                PyErr_SetString(PyExc_KeyError, "Bad key type");
                bpy::throw_error_already_set();
            }
            key_t key = keyproxy();

            // get the corresponding value
            bpy::object valobj{ d[keyobj] };
            bpy::extract<val_t> valproxy{ valobj };
            if (! valproxy.check()) {
                PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Bad value type");
                bpy::throw_error_already_set();
            }
            val_t val = valproxy();
            m[key] = val;
        }

        // remember the location for later
        data->convertible = storage;
    }
};
```

In order to use it, you must create a `Dict2Map` instance so that its constructor gets invoked. One possible way of doing it is to create a static `Dict2Map<key_t, val_t>` variable in the source file where you define the Python wrappers. Using my example:

```
// myclasswrapper.cc
#include "mymap.hh"
#include "dict2map.hh"

// register the converter at runtime
static Dict2Map<char, double> reg{};

#include "boost/python.hpp" // not really necessary
namespace bpy = boost::python;

// wrapping MyClass
bpy::class_<MyClass>("MyClass", "My example class",
  bpy::init<mymap_t>()
)
  // .def(...method wrappers...)
;
```

Now it is possible to create `MyClass` objects on the Python side like this:

```
myclass = MyClass({"foo":1, "bar":2})
```

**Edit**: Python lists can be converted to C++ `std::vector`-s in an analogous manner. Here is the corresponding template:

```
template<typename elem_t>
struct List2Vec {

    /// The type of the vector we convert the Python list into
    typedef std::vector<elem_t> vec_t;

    /// constructor
    /// registers the converter
    List2Vec() {
        bpy::converter::registry::push_back(
            &convertible,
            &construct,
            bpy::type_id<vec_t>()
#ifdef BOOST_PYTHON_SUPPORTS_PY_SIGNATURES
            , &bpy::converter::wrap_pytype<&PyList_Type>::get_pytype
#endif
        );
    }

    /// Check if conversion is possible
    static void* convertible(PyObject* objptr) {
        return PyList_Check(objptr)? objptr: nullptr;
    }

    /// Perform the conversion
    static void construct(
        PyObject* objptr,
        bpy::converter::rvalue_from_python_stage1_data* data
    ) {
        // convert the PyObject pointed to by `objptr` to a bpy::list
        bpy::handle<> objhandle{ bpy::borrowed(objptr) };   // "smart ptr"
        bpy::list lst{ objhandle };

        // get a pointer to memory into which we construct the vector
        // this is provided by the Python side somehow
        void* storage = 
            reinterpret_cast<
                bpy::converter::rvalue_from_python_storage<vec_t>*
            >(data)->storage.bytes;

        // placement-new allocate the result
        new(storage) vec_t{};

        // iterate over the list `lst`, fill up the vector `vec`
        int elemcount{ static_cast<int>(bpy::len(lst)) };
        vec_t& vec{ *(static_cast<vec_t *>(storage)) };
        for (int i = 0; i < elemcount; ++i) {
            // get the element
            bpy::object elemobj{ lst[i] };
            bpy::extract<elem_t> elemproxy{ elemobj };
            if (! elemproxy.check()) {
                PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Bad element type");
                bpy::throw_error_already_set();
            }
            elem_t elem = elemproxy();
            vec.push_back(elem);
        }

        // remember the location for later
        data->convertible = storage;
    }
};
```